# trying to break the li for every 3 elements in a row

Tags: html, css

I have this code, it is working  but not entirely

```css
ul {
  columns: 3;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is with the above, if everything is divided in 3 rows, if I have an extra element, it is not creating a new line and adding only 1 element to it, neither it does for 2, it always seems to have columns to be shown in 3 instead of li breaking at extra  ones.

I am open to div, or span, or li if my code should work as to what I am trying to do with li, I will apply css to hide that piece of code which shows bullets.

Comment: "*It is working but not entirely*" - what - *exactly* - are you trying to do? English may not be your first language, so while your question is welcome here (so long as you can improve it to be understood), you may have better assistance on [es.so], [pt.so], [ru.so], or [ja.so] (if you speak any of those languages).

Comment: did you tried running my code and i have explained it very clearly that it works but the elements are in odd sequence, it does not show those elements, it always expect the elements will be 3 or 6 or 9, it never works with 4, or 5 elements

Comment: I have tried running your code, but seeing thirty `<li>` elements all with the same "Some text" does very little to communicate what the problem is. While you may be certain you explained it "*very clearly*" I'm afraid I - personally - cannot understand the problem you want help to solve. Others may understand, and the problem may well be mine. That's fine, it simply means that I'm unable to help you unless you clarify the problem.

Comment: I think the fact that the original code sample had an even 30 `<li>` elements was obscuring the issue. I've reduced it to 7 `<li>`s to better demonstrate the issue with an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the columns are each being populated completely before moving on to the next column. This will leave you with an unbalanced final column.

By making the `ul` element a flex container, the `li` elements are displayed side by side. The `flex-wrap` property set to wrap allows the `li` elements to wrap to a new line when the container width is exceeded.

The `flex-basis` property set to `calc(100% / 3)` specifies that each `li` should take up one-third of the container's width.

Please see if this CSS works for you:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: if needed i can change it to div, because the above works but if i apply other css properties like gap or anything else, its breaking apart

Comment: Try to reduce the `flex-basis` value to accomodate the additional space. Try setting it to 95% as a starting point.